# Where are nslookup and dig gone?

Tags: networking, packages

I installed my Raspberry Pi out of the box. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find neither `nslookup` nor `dig`.

Where can I find them? Which package do I need to add?

- `uname -a` is:

  ```
  Linux brambleberry 3.12.28+ #709 PREEMPT Mon Sep 8 15:28:00 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
  ```
- From file `/etc/os-release`:

  ```
  PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
  ```

Comment: try sudo apt-get install dnsutils

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get Bluetooth/Bluetooth.h for Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/where-to-get-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-for-raspberry-pi)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev 1) I fail to see relation between the two questions (network tool vs bluetooth tool). 2) I was looking **years** ago for the package that will provide me with `dig` or `nslookup`, again I fail to see answer in linked bluetooth question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use

```
 sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```

After installation, `nslookup` now works:

```
me > nslookup 8.8.8.8
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa    name = google-public-dns-a.google.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Comment: [Have a look here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/191977/25985) if you want to know how to figure this out.  That question is closed, but rob's answer on it is worth reading because it uses the `--regex` option to `apt-file` (which is explained in my answer).  You can always click through to the duplicate as well.

Comment: When I tried it, I got "`Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main libisc84 armhf 1:9.8.4.dfsg.P1-6+nmu2+deb7u3 404 Not Found`" (and seven other 404's). (I have Debian 7.8/ kernel 3.18.7 - and the same content in /etc/os-release as in the question.)

Comment: Doing `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get` fixed the problem, as in [an answer to *"apt-get installation doesn't work on Raspberry Pi"*](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9307/apt-get-installation-doesnt-work-on-raspberry-pi/9320#9320).

Comment: I tried it on a second Raspberry Pi. Only the first, `sudo apt-get update`, is necessary (potentially saving hundreds of megabytes download (and a lot of time)).