# sudo apt-get not working

Tags: apt, sudo

I was trying to install `re2c`  but terminal replies the following:

```
sudo apt-get install re2c
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  re2c
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 202 kB of archives.
After this operation, 385 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  re2c
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main re2c armhf 0.13.5-1
  Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (2001:41c9:1:3ce::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/r/re2c/re2c_0.13.5-1_armhf.deb  Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80 (2001:41c9:1:3ce::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Note: I have an internet connection and the browser is working easily. The only problem is with `apt-get`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: This may be a temporary situtation. I am also assuming that you have run apt-get update or with --fix-missing as mentoned in the error message.

Comment: @SteveRobillard, he probably did, `re2c_0.13.5-1_armhf.deb` is the actual version at the time of writing.

Comment: Any time I have seen this I just try again later.

Answer (score 4):

If this isn't a transitory problem with the server in question, you may be in a situation where IPv6 isn't being routed for you. In that case, you could force IPv4 routing per ethanol100's instructions in this forum post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=125231

```
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true
```

If that works, you can make it permanent by adding this as /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4:

```
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes (but not rarely), `raspbian.org` goes out of service. If you really can't wait, I suggest replacing it or adding another mirror.

You can completely replace your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with the one below. I think the file is self-explanatory.

Make sure to run `apt-get update` after you update the source list.

```
# THIS IS THE DEFAULT ENTRY.
# To replace this, comment it out (add a # at the beginning). 
# Make sure to enable at least one other entry from the list below if you 
# decide to disable this one.
# Its okay to enable more than one mirror.
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

# MIRRORS BELOW.
# Uncomment a line (remove the #) to use it as a mirror.
# Take note I am using Raspbian Jessie. Change yours accordingly.
# -PANDALION98

#EUROPE
#deb http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/archive.raspbian.org/archive/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://raspbian.insideelectronics.co.uk/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://raspbian.lag.re/raspbian jessie main contrib non-free rpi

#NORTH AMERICA
#deb http://mirror.nexcess.net/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://mirror.glennmcgurrin.com/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

#SOUTH AMERICA
#deb http://raspbian.ufms.br/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://raspbian.c3sl.ufpr.br/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

#ASIA
#deb http://mirror.devunt.kr/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://mirror.rise.ph/raspbian/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that it's trying to get to an out of date mirror?

```
Sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then try again?

Comment: `re2c_0.13.5-1_armhf.deb` is the newest version of the package at the moment. Also, `apt-get upgrade` will certainly not help here and might do something the OP doesn't want.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the pi is not connected to the internet. To confirm internet connectivity, do the following (from a command prompt):

```
ping google.com
```

The response should look something like the following if you have internet connectivity:

```
PING google.com (74.125.24.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from de (74.125.24.139): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=23.9 ms
64 bytes from de (74.125.24.139): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=17.1 ms
```

If you get no response from the ping, then you need to check your pi internet connection. You could start here: 
https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup.pdf

Comment: The OP is using IPv6 (so he won't see the same thing as you), and he also says his browser is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused when `raspbian.org` is down.

Please use one of the alternate Raspbian Respository Mirrors that is close to you from here: http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors. Check the `Issues` column to avoid using the mirror that has known issues.

Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with elevated permissions. Example:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment out original server URL and add new line with the mirror URL as follows (just an example):

```
# deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
deb http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/raspbian/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Save file.

Now run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt --fix-missing upgrade -y
```

Now try installing what you were trying to install.

```
sudo apt install re2c
```

Hope it works for you. It did for me.